# CSS: Jquery UI button position differs next to INPUT vs. Header Name

Tags: jquery, html, css

**SETUP**: I have a table header that I've included a JQuery UI search button. Once clicking this button, it replaces the header name with a search box.

**ISSUE**: After clicking the button, it *appears* to the user that the button moves slightly. This is because it's positioned next to a INPUT box or just text. See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pwharff/gNG44/

To get arround this, I have tried to use float and display

```
float: right
display: inline-block
```

Essentially, markup for the button needs to be in the same position no matter if next to the INPUT or just Text.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

To help **clarify** this post:

Before clicking search button:

[image: before]

After clicking search button:

[image: after]

Button moves.

Comment: and...I wonder what then happens

Comment: your fiddle aint working

Comment: Sorry guys, fixed link. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shot in the dark since I have no clue what your talking about but from the sound of it, it will work. Apply position:relative; to the table header and position:absolute to the button, and give it some position numbers: top:5px;right:0px;

Absolutely positioned elements are out of the DOM flow and should stay put.

Comment: it will work, although it is always my last resort

Comment: You are correct, it did work. Many thanks. Why your last resort?

Comment: I just feel that if you structure your markup correctly, like using fixed widths when needed, or nesting properties that float left and right, you should rarely need to use absolute positioning. Although, there are some things that require absolute positioning, like image overlays or lightboxes